# Cant get simulated location to work on xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, location, simulate

He guys,

Iam having some problem's with xcode, when iam trying to test my app on a different location , using the an simulated location i cant get it to work on the iphones. I have tried to get it to work by using the simulate location tab in the debug bar and selecting one of the standard locations and on of my own GPX files, but nothing works. I also tried changing the location by going to edit scheme and change default location to any other location but with the same results. I also don't get any error's or messages, just nothing.

I hope you guys can help me out i have tried allot but nothing helps and really need it to work for my project.

Using xcode 10.1
Ios 12.1.4 & 12.1.2